# Django check box from models WITHOUT using the form.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

How to render a checkbox with multiple selection allowed in Django by just using the model.py file and without using the form.py file?

This is my code (which works however only for dropdown single selection and not checkbox multiple selection):

```
from django.db import models

class PropertyAmenities(models.Model):

# here below is the list of multiple choices that I would like the user to be able to select
PROPERTY_AMENITIES_CHOICES = (
    ('maid_room', 'MAID_ROOM'),
    ('study','STUDY'),
    ('balcony_or_terrace', 'BALCONY_OR_TERRACE'))

# the below only work as "dropdown single choice". How can I have it as a "multiple choice check box"?
property_amenities = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=PROPERTY_AMENITIES_CHOICES)
```

Question: How to modify the model class without having to touch or use the form.py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution found is the following library: "django-multiselectfield"
Do the following step and use the following as base guide:

```
pip install django-multiselectfield
```

or if you use pycharm or any other IDE install the library from the interpreter setting/library section: "django-multiselectfield"

go to settings.py file and add the following in the INSTALLED_APPS:

```
'multiselectfield'
```

go to the model.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

MY_CHOICES = (('maid', 'MAID'),
              ('study', 'STUDY'),
              ('balcony', 'BALCONY'))


class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = MultiSelectField(choices=MY_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.my_field
```

go to the views.py file:
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import MyModel
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

```
class Index(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'multi/index.html', {'my_model_all': MyModel.objects.all()})


class CreateMyModel(CreateView):
   model = MyModel
   fields = '__all__'
   success_url = reverse_lazy('multi:home')
```

go to the urls.py file(of your app obviously):

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

app_name = 'multi'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('jack/create/', CreateMyModel.as_view(), name='create_rock')
]
```

Finally make sure that you have in templates/your_app_folder in my case "templates/multi" the following files: "index.html", "mymodel_form.html".

index.html file as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="{% url 'multi:create_rock' %}">Add Form</a>
</body>
</html>
```

mymodel_form.html as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Multi Checkbox Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't forget to do the manage.py makemigrations and migrate after having saved all files before running the server.
Run a manage.py check for good measure.
Finally runserver.